# Use dummy API key for Travis CI

Tags: android, api, build, travis-ci

My Android app uses Google Payments and I store the API Keys in a values xml that is not added to VCS (used .gitignore file). I reference the value as `R.string.api_licence` from my code.

When I setup travis for CI, it was complaining that `R.string.api_licence` was not found. As a work around, I checked in a dummy text file with empty value for the key and rename the extension to xml from travis build script.

While this is working for now,
1 - This doesn't seem like a perfect solution
2 - Android Studio complains that the dummy txt file name should be of xml extension, and I have to delete it locally to work, which leads me to accidentally commit and break the builds sometimes

Travis script file: https://github.com/midhunhk/message-counter/blob/master/.travis.yml

Notes: I am a self taught Android developer. I don't require the real API keys to be used for CI process. I did some considerable research on this topic and couldn't get a specific answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following approach can be used for solving this issue. I never got to test this as I changed my API implementation and may not need to store the API key in the source code.

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings